# How to render separate monochrome layers?

Tags: materials

I have this logo:

[image: Logo]
.blend file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/1bib5ds8oufc9s9/logo.blend

The thing is I'm trying to make it lasercut. My lasercutter supports two colours - that is black and white (monochrome).
So, with the above logo I made it monochrome in Photoshop:
[image: Photoshop monochrome]

As you can see, no matter how I try, the logo will not actually work (the text is not readable)

But, this can be repaired by rendering each part of the logo black or white. For example, the background splodge could be in places white, and where there are the holes, black.

Then each of the circles could have an outline of black and the text could appear white, but to create the tilt effect, the sides of the text could be in black.

As you can see, I am trying to make the text visible by making certain parts black and some white. I could change the material colours in Blender, or something, but then it will do a gradient, which is the issue.

Thank you for reading my essay! ;) And I look forward to hearing from answers

Comment: The frame used for the logo: 627

Comment: You could use *Shadeless* materials and disable anti-aliasing.

Comment: Would you confirm [which is the one you want](http://pasteall.org/pic/show.php?id=67276)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, monochrome effect can be easily done by **ColorRamp** node:

[image]

**To your question:**

As you mentioned, it seems that the only problem now is the tilt/side area on the text. I suggest to consider taking the advantage of **Material Index** here:

[image]

To do so:

- First, convert the Text objects to mesh (Shortcut is <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>. You may want to remove doubles and correct normal directions after that);
- Select all sided faces, then assign a new material to the selection (even can be the exact duplication as the original one, if necessary);
- Set a different **Pass Index** value in setting of this material;
- Toggle Material Index passes in Render Layer setting for outputting. You can then use it to separate the tilt/side area and have it controlled separately.

---

If you don't want to do it for compositing use, using plain materials with **Shadelss** toggled can also be an easier way:

[image]

---

**UPDATE:**

Inspired by gandalf3's cool answer, here is the option for outlined result, also with more control by ColorRamp.

[image]

You may also consider to generate outlines by **[FreeStyle](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Render/Freestyle)**, though relatively inefficient and less flexible in this case.

Comment: in OPs question you can see that the attached B&W is not the desired output because you cannot read all the word. I believe you replicated this result.

Comment: @Vader Oh, How can it be... Surprised that I missed points there. I'll try reediting it asap. Thx.

Comment: Answer is updated.

Comment: @LeonCheung Like this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Mvp54.png gandalf3 did it for me, but now I am still unsure how to do it... Maybe his comment above is useful.

Comment: Whatever is in black is engraved.

Comment: Whatever is in white is not engraved.

Comment: You see, I'd like the text to stick out, so it is in white

Comment: What gandalf3 suggests is the similar thing, if you want to separate the monochrome layers, you should separate materials. And, for compositing, you should also separate by Material Index to get specific pass as mask. [Here](http://pasteall.org/pic/show.php?id=67310) is the Shadeless way, sample file [here](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/27042) if needed.

Comment: If you want to invert the mask color as shown in my image, then just set the new material index for the material in first slot, and leave the second one as 0. Like [this](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/27043). However, it's just the mask used for compositing, not actually the color used as final result.

Comment: OMG, thank you for all your time writing this answer and laboriously putting links in your comments! Thank you again! Very interesting...

Comment: This answer certainly does deserve my upvote!

Answer (score 3):

[image: Black and white logo]

My answer is pretty much the same as Leon Cheung's, but I used different color ramp nodes for both layers and added separate outlines using the *Dilate/Erode* node:

[image]

[**Example blendfile**](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/27047)

Comment: Deserves my upvote, but Leon Cheung's was very detailed. Thank you for your time and thank you for helping the Blender community out there!

Comment: And also very useful to have text for every node to explain. How did you do that? Thanks ;)

Comment: @TimTimmy Add *frame nodes* (add node > Layout > Frame). I edited the *Label* of the node for the text. You can also parent nodes to frame nodes (Ctrl+P).

Comment: Great for the prompt reply. Thank you for keeping this Blender community alive!